# How to find the middle 3 characters of a word with an odd number of characters using substring? (C++)

Tags: c++, string

This is my assignment:

> The midfix of 3 is the middle 3 characters of a string. Given a string input, output the middle three characters of that string. Assume the word length is always odd and at least three characters.
>
> Hint: Use the string function substr().
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> xxxtoyxxx
>
> the output is:
>
> Midfix: toy

I am unable to get my code to fit for any word with an odd word length (i.e. the code works for `flags` (`lag`) but not for `xxxtoyxxx` or `cat`. I know how to find characters on a specific word, but do not know how to make it work for any odd word length word.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   string a;

   cin >> a;

   int length = a.length();

   int middle = length/2;

   string c = a.substr(middle-1, middle+1);

   cout << "Midfix: " << c << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always read the documentation of a function you don't know...

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd parameter of [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) expects a **count** of the characters you want to extract (always 3 in this case), but you are instead trying to use the parameter as an **index** to the end of the substring you want to extract.

The reason why your code "works" for `flags` (and any other word with the same length) is because its `length` is 5, so its `middle` is `2`, and thus `middle+1` is 3, which is the correct *count* of characters you need to extract with `substr()`.

This is not true for any other words whose `length` is not 5, eg:

- `xxxtoyxxx`: `length` is 9, so `middle` is 4, thus `middle+1` is 5, not 3.
- `cat`: `length` is 3, so `middle` is 1, thus `middle+1` is 2, not 3.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   string a;
   cin >> a;

   size_t length = a.length();
   size_t middle = length/2;

   string c = a.substr(middle-1, 3);

   cout << "Midfix: " << c << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/tPE78b)